Who does Porco actually love? Gina or Fio?
I've just watched Porco Rosso, produced by Studio Ghibli and directed by Hayao Miyazaki. The whole film was just super good, but I had some trouble figuring out the romance part of the film.
At the start, it seems like Porco likes Gina and vice versa. However, after the introduction of Fio Piccolo as Porco's aircraft mechanic's granddaughter, it turns out Fio likes Porco too. Fio was only introduced almost half-way into the film, and coupled with the fact that Gina explicitly stated to Curtiss that she loves Porco, it seems like Gina would be Porco's girlfriend (if he ever decides to leave some time for romance).
On the other hand, however, Fio is always with Porco in the latter half of the film, encouraging and helping him, and she also explicitly stated that she likes Porco. Additionally, she first kisses Porco on the cheek when she says she likes him, and actually proceeds to a full-fledged romantic kiss on the lips at the end of the film.
So my questions are: who likes Porco more? Who does Porco like more?  And, most important of all, given the ending and circumstances, who is more likely to meet Porco again? The film is sort of a cliffhanger, especially with the romance part, so I would like anyone to share their thoughts on this.

"And, most important of all, who will most likely be Porco's romantic partner if he ever had one?" I'm afraid this will be speculative and opinion-based unless there's an official statement.

@AkiTanaka But most questions about anime and manga are opinion based, because official sources won't answer such questions. Anyway, I'm new to the Anime & Manga SE,  so can you please describe what kinds of questions are not opinion based, or, more generally, what questions are suitable for this site?

Because in the [Tour], it says that questions asking for anime recommendations, the release time of a new season of anime or manga, or asking for the name of an anime are all off-topic. So, what's on topic here? This question is the most on-topic one that I have, given the conditions already stated.

In the [Tour], it does say that "Plot, character, or setting explanations" are on topic here.  I think I am asking about the plot and characters here. Although I may be wrong. So, please tell me what kinds of questions are more on-topic, valuable, and beneficial for the community here?

I guess it's a wording issue. The first 2 questions "who likes Porco more? Who does Porco like more?" are okay because it assumes for the fact from official sources, and if there aren't, then it's still okay (potential answer: "it's never been stated officially, but..."). The next question is explicitly inviting the answerers to speculate "if he ever had one", which will be correct for any answer (e.g. popularity vote). I believe removing this question should be enough to make the whole questions on-topic, or otherwise by rewording it.

@AkiTanaka Thanks for the suggestion, but I do still want that last question in my post, so could you please tell me how to rephrase it to be on-topic? Thanks for any suggestions!

I'm not sure if I could rephrase it better. The best I could come up with is "In the end, did Porco end up with someone?" which might be obvious since it's a cliffhanger and hence your question. (That said, I won't vote to close this question just because of that, nor I can't, because my vote as a moderator is binding...)

@AkiTanaka Thanks for the advice, maybe I'll think of some way to rephrase it myself.

@AkiTanaka I've just edited my question, check it out. And please tell me if you think it solves the problem or  improves the post.

I personally think that's better, and I don't really have any problems with it :)

@AkiTanaka Thanks for your feedback, and also thanks for your suggestion because I think my question is now more well-received.

I happened to read the original story for Porco Rosso and a memoir by Ghibli Producer (this) . In the original, there was no GIna, and she was an addition in the movie to 'explain' why Porco is a pig in the first place. In this sense, from Hayao Miyazaki's perspective, Fio may be more important.
